# Retrieve object name

Tags: vb.net

I need to retrieve the name of an instanced object (not the type name...)

I have seen that the GetProperties() function gets the child properties name but i need the name of the current object

```
Public Class Class1
    Private mValore As String

    Public Property Valore As String
        Get
            Return mValore
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            mValore = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class


Public Class Class2
    Private mMickey As new Class1

    Public Property Mickey As Class1
        Get
            Return mMickey
        End Get
        Set(value As Class1)
            mMickey = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

I need to obtain inside Class1 the name of instanced object in Class2: "Mickey"

Is it possible ?
Thanks in advice for all that will answer me.

Comment: Objects do not have names.  Variables, methods, properties have names.  Consider the NameOf operator.

Comment: If you need the class type that initialized Class1, it's in the [StackTrace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace), one frame before the current (read from the Class1 constructor). One frame further, there's the name of the method where the initialization occurred. Why do you thing you need to know this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Hans Passant, objects don't have names.

So if you really need names, you may introduce them, as a property or field. You may employ [CallerMemberNameAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?view=netframework-4.8) to automatically pass the caller name to e.g. constructor.

Another thing, objects might be created outside `Class2`, indeed in the `Mickey ... Set` setter you are assigning `mMickey` field to an object from somewhere outside, so the object might have a different name. I would prefer to create a copy of object instead of just assignment, then we can assign any name to it and it will not collide with the previous name. An example could be:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Class Class1
    Private mValore As String

    Public ReadOnly Name As String

    Public Sub New(mValore As String, <CallerMemberName> Optional callerMemberName As String = Nothing)
        Me.mValore = mValore
        Me.Name = callerMemberName
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Valore As String
        Get
            Return mValore
        End Get
    End Property
End Class


Public Class Class2
    Private mMickey As Class1

    Public Property Mickey As Class1
        Get
            Return mMickey
        End Get
        Set(value As Class1)
            mMickey = New Class1(mValore:=value.Valore)
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: @HardCode `Optional` continued to exist in VB.NET mainly because of their existence in COM APIs. [Even C# eventually got optional parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments), however late.

Comment: @HardCode I think you have to use `Optional` for `CallerMemberName` to work correctly.  I don't think this example could be implemented using an overload.

Answer (score 0):

If Class2 only has one property, you can just get the *only* property's name

```vb
Public Class Class1
    Public ReadOnly Property Valore As String
        Get
            Return GetType(Class2).GetProperties().Single().Name
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

Public Class Class2
    Public Property Mickey As Class1
End Class
```

Or if it has multiple properties, you can just get the *first* property's name

```vb
Public Class Class1
    Public ReadOnly Property Valore As String
        Get
            Return GetType(Class2).GetProperties().First().Name
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

Public Class Class2
    Public Property Mickey As Class1
    Public Property Mouse As String
End Class
```

That returns the first property in order in which the properties are defined. So if the order is changed, it breaks.

Surely there must be more qualifying information to lead us to a solution. Can I make the assumption that you are only interested in the name of the property whose type is Class1? Then you can also filter on the property's type

```vb
Public Class Class1
    Public ReadOnly Property Valore As String
        Get
            Return GetType(Class2).GetProperties().Where(Function(pi) pi.PropertyType Is GetType(Class1)).Single().Name
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

Public Class Class2
    Public Property Mouse As String
    Public Property Mickey As Class1
End Class
```

I think this is exactly what you're looking for. But if not, let me know and we can work it out.

Comment: Excellent !!!
This is exactly what i want !!!
You have no idea how long I have searched the internet to resolve this problem.
Thanks a lot